# Errors were encountered while processing: android-studio

Tags: apt, software-installation, android

Whenever I install a new software or I use update command on the terminal i always get this error message and update is also interrupted. what do i do?

I encounter the following error message-

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 android-studio
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: can you post output of these commands :- `sudo dpkg --configure -a sudo apt-get install -f cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up android-studio (4.8.2-ubuntu0) ...
unzip:  cannot find or open /opt/android-studio-ide-*, /opt/android-studio-ide-*.zip or /opt/android-studio-ide-*.ZIP.

No zipfiles found.
rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/android-studio-ide-*’: No such file or directory
find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package android-studio (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 android-studio

Comment: root@divyendu:~# sudo apt-get install -f cat /etc/apt/sources.list
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cat
E: Unable to locate package /etc/apt

Comment: these are the output of the command you told to execute.

Comment: the error message that i have posted is the full error message that appears at the end of any command.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the package manager continues following an interrupt doesn't mean that the package itself will not contain errors.

Try removing the package and starting the process over again.

First purge the package:

```
sudo apt-get purge android-studio
```

Then fix any remaining issues:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a   or
sudo apt-get update
```

Run the installation again:

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```